# instal phpmyadmin on web server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm working on a web site with joomla 1.5, so to import the data base I need phpMyAdmin but unfortunately I have just the ftp account on server e.g (ftp.eXXXX.com). I upload phpMyAdmin to my ftp and I did this config :

and about the host in the configuration I try :www.mywebsite.com
                                               ftp.eXXXX.com
but I got this :

```
#2005 - Unknown MySQL server host 'http://www.mywebsite.com' (1)
```

How can I host the database ??

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 *
 * @package phpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'DXXXX'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '????????????';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

/* Storage database and tables */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * default = 30
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * Use graphically less intense menu tabs
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['LightTabs'] = true;

/**
 * disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false  allow editing
 *   'blob' allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'  disallow editing
 * default = blob
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = 'false';

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * default display direction (horizontal|vertical|horizontalflipped)
 */
//$cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'vertical';


/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 *
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/*
 * You can find more configuration options in Documentation.html
 * or here: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config
 */
?>
```

Comment: Surely "http://www.mywebsite.com" should be "http://www.eXXX.com" if that is the server name.

Comment: i try "mywebsite.com" and "eXXX.com" and localhost dont work , so i must have a name of mysql sever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually putting value 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' (which is better in any case I guess) works fine, but if your server provide access to DB physically on another host, it usually gives you the address in your admin panel (like cPanel) and you put that value inside the ['host'] = '...'; also you might need to put $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket'; in that case

Comment: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket' dont work how can i use it ??

Comment: Are you sure your provider gives you capability of accessing by socket? As I've previously stated, usually they have mysql on the same host, so you just write $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Comment: Sorry, as I've just read from your another comment, you don't have the SQL server on same host, so $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '10.0.217.122'; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'XXXXX'; can be ok for you... otherwise try putting same username as you use for another access'es instead of 'root'

Comment: sir i try root and the same username of ftp but  Access denied for this users , can i contact the server of this ip adress ?? or any idea ??

Comment: If you had access to any host in that network I could suggest few things, but I'm pretty sure you do not have ssh access to those hosts. Also have u tried changins 'extension' in the config from mysqli to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Well, MySQL is not a HTTP protocol, so you'll definitely want to leave out the `http://`. Normally, setting the host to just `"localhost"` will work fine.

Comment: i try it and : #2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Comment: Are you sure the server you're using even *has* MySQL? If so, it'll probably also have phpMyAdmin.

Comment: no there is no phpMyadmin on the server , they give me the ftp  account and this : sql server : 10.0.217.122 and the pass XXXXX but no user name and lose contact with who give me that , any idea ??

Comment: Enter that IP address as the `host` value. You already have the password - I'd assume that the username is the same as your FTP username.

Comment: Then contact your hosting provider.

Comment: i didnt host at the 1st time can i know the provider from the ftp adresse ??